# Rudin Exercise 18 Chapter 8 - Elegant solution?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, trigonometry, inequality

> **Exercise**: Define
> $$f(x) = x^3 - \sin^2(x)\tan(x)$$
> $$g(x) = 2x^2 - \sin^2(x) -x\tan(x)$$
> Find out, for each of these two functions, whether it is positive or negative for all $x \in (0, \pi/2)$, or whether it changes sign. Prove your answer.

**The problem**

The standard solution to this exercise requires to compute the derivatives of $f$ and $g$ as many times as six and five respectively, however I think that such an answer is neither illuminating nor typical for Rudin's exercises. While trying to solve it by myself I would have guessed the solution to rely on some clever inequality involving sine and tangent. In particular, I have noticed that the presence of $x^3$ and $2x^2$ is not random and this is something that the iterated derivatives do not highlight. Indeed, by the Mean Value Theorem, one can link the behavior of sine and tangent of $x$ to that of $x$ multiplied by some constant, so that, for instance, $\sin^2x\tan x$ behaves like a multiple of $x^3$.

I would like to know whether there is an actual elegant solution or if this exercise were mere computation.

---

As always, any comment or answer is much appreciated and let me know if I can explain myself clearer!

Comment: Think about Taylor. The result is immediate

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I have actually tried using Taylor (with Lagrange’s Remainder) but to no avail. Could you specify what did you have in mind?

Comment: The term $\tan(x)$ takes the functions to $-\infty$. How does they behave close to $0$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Close to 0 both functions converge to 0, however the functions may still change sign between 0 and $\pi/2$.

Comment: For sure but the basic series are valid for all $x$; there is an explicit formula for the coefficients and ou can prove that, by thier definition, they are all negative. QED

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I still don’t see how to do it. I may be proceeding wrongly, however I computed the Taylor series with Lagrange’s Remainder up to the second order for both sine and tangent and then I substituted them in $f(x)$ but I have obtained a mess that is no better than taking derivatives.

Comment: Perhaps this helps in  determining the Taylor coefficients:  $\sin^2x\tan x=-{1\over 2}\sin(2x)+\tan x$ and $\sin^2x={1\over 2}[1-\cos(2x)]$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I have tried using your suggestion but once again I have found nothing useful when I substituted the Taylor polynomial in. I do not understand what I am doing wrong.